# git push origin branch, not to tag , error: dst refspec release/2.1 matches more than one

Tags: git, git-push

In my remote repository I have a branch call release/2.1 as well as tag with the same name. When I try to push code from local branch to remote branch it gives an error saying `error: dst refspec release/2.1 matches more than one`.
I can't delete the tag. Any solution to push the code specifically to the remote branch, not to tag.

Thanks

Comment: You can try pushing to `refs/heads/release/2.1`. All branches in git are stored under `refs/heads` while tags are under `refs/tags`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+dst+refspec+matches+more+than+one